# Using an ESB system to replicate data among databases

Tags: replication, esb, mule

I work in a small supermarket chain (4 stores).   Each store has its own local database which contains information of each product, prices, and transactions that have ocurred on the store.  In addition, each store needs to replicate this information back and forth to a central location.

Right now we are using something called SQLRemote, which is a feature of Sybase's SQL Anywhere database.  It works, but sometimes fails and is difficult to manage.  To its' credit, SQLRemote actually wasn't designed for this type of scenarios, so it could be said that we are using it incorrectly.

I was thinking that an ESB system such as Mule (or ChainBuilder which seems easier to set up) might be a good alternative to SQL remote.    I understand that these systems can detect when changes occur in the database (i.e. when records are added, modified or deleted), and can be set up to deliver a message in a transaction.

Would this be a viable solution to my scenario?

Best regards,
Edgard

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I am sure Mule should be able to do this.

However I work for a company which provides Fuse ESB which is using Apache projects such as Apache ServiceMix, Apache ActiveMQ, Apache Camel and Apache CXF.

We have a user story about a very big retailler in US which uses Fuse ESB to integrate their stores and warehouses and whatnot
http://fusesource.com/collateral/17

Fuse ESB
http://fusesource.com/products/enterprise-servicemix/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Mule can support this scenario thought it might be overkill. There are targeted database replication solutions out there. The advantage of Mule would be it's ability to handle failure and other scenarios where you need the workflow to be adapted based on what is happening. This allows you to build a very robust solution.

Mule flows could be a very good choice to address this problem. It's a new feature of Mule 3 designed for orchestrating integrations like this.